# How to check MenuItem is enabled/disabled in Espresso UI Automation Test

Tags: android, menuitem, android-espresso

I am writing UI Automation tests in Espresso for Android & came across a scenario for which I haven't got any solution so far.

In one `Fragment`, I have `OptionsMenu` with a single item. The state of that `MenuItem` is set according to value from API response.

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.clear();
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_cancel_order, menu);
    MenuItem cancelMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.cancel_order);
    if(something) { // something can be a boolean value from server
        cancelMenuItem.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        cancelMenuItem.setEnabled(false);
    } 
}
```

For UI testing, I need to write test case for checking whether this `MenuItem` is enabled/disabled.

For clicking on the overflowmenu,

```
ViewInteraction actionMenuItemView = onView(
            allOf(withId(R.id.action_settings), withContentDescription("Settings"), isDisplayed()));
actionMenuItemView.perform(click());
```

And so far what I have tried to check the Assertion is given below.

```
onView(allOf(withText("Cancel Order"), withId(R.id.cancel_order))).check(matches(not(isEnabled())));
```

But this fires `NoMatchingViewException` with message

> NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with
>   text: is "Cancel Order" and with id:
>   com.equinix.ecp.betatest:id/cancel_order)

So I tried changing it to

```
onView(allOf(withText("Cancel Order"))).check(matches(not(isEnabled())));
```

Somehow this matched the view but it was not a MenuItem but the TextView inside the MenuItem & since I am setting `setEnabled()` to MenuItem, `check()` Assertion won't work as expected since it is a `TextView`.

So my question is how to write Test for checking enabled/disabled state of MenuItem.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I have the same situation.

Comment: @makovkastar Not actually. But what I did is like, rather than checking for enabled/disabled of menu item, I just perform click operation on menu item & checks whether the item which is in next page is not displayed. So if item is not displayed, then that means click was not performed thereby it means the menu is disabled. Not perfect but for now this is how I did. Waiting for a perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

it would be a good idea to make use of uiautomatorviewer, to put a breakpoint in at the point your test fails, and then inspect your app's layout for clues

it sounds to me that you have two views. One with the id of `R.id.cancel_order` and another with text `"Cancel Order"` which probably has another id (or could/should).
So together they return NoMatchingView, because they aren't the same view.

They could be sibling views, or possibly one is a descendent of another. This is where uiautomatorviewer is very handy for figuring out what's happening on screen

as long as you've installed "Android SDK Platform-Tools" and "Android SDK Tools"
from Terminal:

```
cd /Users/<user name>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
./uiautomatorviewer
```

(it's also helpful to save this as a script and just use an alias shortcut for convenience)

as for your matcher, i would try :

```
onView(allOf(
    withId(R.id.cancel_order),
    hasSibling(withText("Cancel Order")) 
)).check(matches(not(isEnabled())));
```

or change `hasSibling(_)` to `hasDescendent(_)` or `isDescendentOfA(_)`, depending on their relationship (which you can find out by using uiautomatorviewer)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the IDs of the menu items to perform your checks.
I tried it with this menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="at.hellobank.hellomarkets.symbols.DetailActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_1"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
    android:title="Menu1"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_2"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
    android:title="Menu2"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

So one menu item is enabled one is disabled. My test to check this looks like this and is working as expected:

```
@Test
public void testMenuItemsStatus() throws Exception {
    onView(withId(R.id.action_1)).check(matches(isEnabled()));
    onView(withId(R.id.action_2)).check(matches(not(isEnabled())));
}
```

Generally using IDs in tests is better imho because you are more independent of typos and general language. `withText("Cancel Order")` probably will not work if you test the app localized in another language.

Comment: Thank  you for your answer. I already tried with ID also but I got the Exception in that case. Also my menu item xml is little different than the one you used in the answer. 'action_settings' is the main item ID & inside that I have submenu item with id 'cancel_order' & showAsAction="ifRoom"